# Building docker image that downloads large file fails with error

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker. I've been trying it for less than two weeks. We have a service that we'd like to migrate into a container. The service makes use of about 50G worth of data, so we expect the image to be very large. We've written a Dockerfile for it. When we run the build it fails with the ff:

```
ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: write /mnt/spine_features/spine_features_subset.lmdb/data.mdb: input/output error
```

When we check docker ps -a for containers, we can see the build container listed with status:

```
Exited (1) About a minute ago
```

When we try to commit the container, we get the same error:

```
Error response from daemon: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: write /mnt/spine_features/spine_features_subset.lmdb/data.mdb: input/output error
```

We can also docker inspect the container. When we exclude downloading the largest files, we are able to complete building the service image. Is there some sort of configuration we can change succeed while still including the larger files?

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.7
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Fri Aug 19 02:03:02 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.7
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Fri Aug 19 02:03:02 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

docker info

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 22
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:2-7603782-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 214.7 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 67.78 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 39.59 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 37.04 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.11 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.134 (2016-09-07)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.7.4-1-ARCH
Operating System: Arch Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 15.58 GiB
Name: mega-haro
ID: MDQ5:JIT3:BVQX:XYO6:YTXI:HTRE:N2UQ:ML4V:ENIE:DDCO:ZGYF:3P5F
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
 misty:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: Can you post out your Dockerfile? Besides, if you have large amount of data, you probably should consider to put them in an volume ( https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/ ) rather than build them to an image. And if your image larger than 20,30GB, you may experience problems with push and pull.

Comment: I can't, and I don't think it would be very useful. What the Dockerfile does is it runs a pre-existing ansible playbook on the docker machine. One of the tasks in the playbook uses gsutil to sync with a large private file in our cloud. Without our playbook and access to our cloud, you would not be able to build the Dockerfile. I will take a look at mounting volumes. Is there further documentation on the 20/30GB size constraint?

Comment: There is no official document about size constraint. I was experienced such problem about large image and I remember one of docker engineers mentioned that somewhere. Your mileage may vary. You can think again about your design, mounting volumes is a recommended way to manage container's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Haoming Zhang recommended, mounting the host directory into the container is an acceptable solution. We are also exploring the possibility of using FUSE to load the data into the container at runtime instead of baking it into the image during build or having the host pass it into the container when the container is run.